# Module not found: Can't resolve header.js or app.js

Tags: reactjs

Console says that it can't find the module in the directory. I've read about relative paths and tried to redirect but it doesn't seem to work. I am trying to import a header into the app.js file and then show that app.js file into the index.js file.

My index.js:

```
    import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from '../components/ui/App';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

my app.js:

```
 import React from 'react';
import Header from './components/ui/Header';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header />
      Hello!
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: If `app.js` is in the `components/ui` folder, and the name of the file where `Header` is defined is named `header.js`, you would just use `import Header from './header.js';`. The code in the question looks for a folder `components/ui/components/ui`

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all, why not share the screenshot of the project structure.

Second, try this one.

```
import App from '../components/ui/app.js';
```

Third, check your `header.js` to check that it has `export default ...`

Comment: I found the problem; the app.js file was in the ui folder and it needed to be in the components folder.

Thanks @sirius for reaching out